# How to Prevent Wordpress to encode html in post

Tags: wordpress

As as title, how to prevent wp not to encode html in a post?

currently i just need  to prevent **'&'** change to **'`&amp;`'**
The result need to be looks like on editor with html tab mode selected.

```
$content = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_content FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID=xxx");
$content = str_replace('amp;','',$content->post_content);//remove amp;

$wpdb->query("UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET post_content = $content WHERE ID = xxx;");
```

but that code still encode the html.

update:
and also how to implement content filter(prevent to encode some text) in collaboration with `wp_insert_post()` function

update[SOLVED]: [stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9301/how-to-prevent-wordpress-to-encode-html-in-post)

```
$content = get_post_field('post_content', XXX, 'raw');
$content = str_replace('amp;', '', $content);
$wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, array( 'post_content' => $content ), array( 'ID' => XXX ) );
```

Comment: Just a pointer you might want to try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com, completely dedicated to WordPress, might be quicker for you :-)

Comment: thank you. but currently no one give answer :)

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php $content = htmlentities( html_entity_decode($content) ); ?>
```

This code will print HTML tags, and then decode HTML entities (like `&amp;` to `&`).

Oh, and with `wp_insert_post()`, do:

```
// Create post object
$my_post = array(
  'post_content' => $content,
  'post_id' => POST_ID # update the post with the same ID as POST_ID
);
```

You can use the escape function as a shortcode:

```
function escape_html_func( $attrs, $content = "" ) {
  return htmlentities( html_entity_decode($content) );
}
add_shortcode( 'escape', 'escape_html_func' );
```

like `[escape]<span>Hello!</span>[/escape]` in blog posts. Is this what you meant by content filter?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't try but seems if use wp_insert_post() its still encode it. But in stackexchange has answer it.

Comment: You're welcome. Saw the answer at Stackexchange, although I think you should use my code with htmlentities instead of a str_replace since it catches more than just "amp;" (and what if you you write amp; in another context?). Anyway, just glad to help. Tried my shortcode?